# Implementing user session in Sencha and SpringBoot

Tags: authentication, sencha-touch, spring-boot, backend

I am trying to make a web app in Sencha Touch with Springboot as my back-end. My app is going to have users and each one of them is going to have their own separate activity. How do I make my app "know" what user is logged in so it can display their specific details? I am a newbie and don't know exactly how this needs to be done, especially on the server side (Springboot). If somebody could throw some light, that would be awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are planning to use Spring Security, the current-user data can be obtained through its principal. There are a few ways to get the principal. One way is to have a principal parameter in the controller method, and Spring will inject it. Like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String currentUserName(Principal principal) {
    return principal;
}
```

Another way would be to have a utility method like this:

```
public static User getUser() {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (auth != null) {
      Object principal = auth.getPrincipal();
      if (principal instanceof User) {
        return (U) principal;
      }
    }
    return null;      
}
```

This can then be called from the controller method.